# PDF not responsive within object

Tags: html, object, pdf, responsive-design, division

I have an object tag within a div and a pdf file within the object tag. The div itself is responsive but I cannot get the pdf itself to scale along with the object. I will show the difference between 2 screens-

[image: screenshot]

Code-

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div style="width: 62.5%">
<div style='position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0px; padding-
bottom: 56.3%;'>
<a><object style='position: absolute; left: 27.8%; top: 0px; width: 
100%; height: 231%' type="application/pdf" data="resume.pdf" 
class="border"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect the PDF file. It can have opening settings which contain a preferred zoom level. If that level is at a fixed percentage and not set to fit the page width, the observed behaviour is to be expected.

Comment: I am looking at it in Adobe reader and the zoom settings only seem to apply to how it is viewed on my computer and not on my browser. Will it only work this way?

Comment: @JasonStylls posted some new code enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design and iframe tag will work here is the HTML and CSS code

```
    <div class="flex-container">

    <section class="first">

    <div id="container">
        <iframe src="docs/your.pdf" ></iframe>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #container{
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 70.25%;/*was 56.28*/
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;   
}

#container iframe{
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

This code was written for an embedded youtube video make changes for pdf file